# libgdx box2d raycast closest fixture

Tags: libgdx, raycasting, closest, fixture

i'm using RayCastCallback interface ıf LibGDX. I couldn't find a way to get closest point from start of the ray. It returns random fixtures that hit by the ray. How can i get the closest collision point between ray and the fixture?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you've got most of the code there, since you're getting fixtures back from your raycast. You'll just need to loop through all fixtures hit by the raycast and remember the closest one. Something like:

```java
public class SomeClass {
    
    private World world;
    private Vector2 fromPoint;
    private Vector2 toPoint;
    private Vector2 collisionPoint = new Vector2();
    float closestFraction = 1.0f;
    
    // ... rest of code ...
    
    private void calculateCollisionPoint() {
        RayCastCallback callback = new RayCastCallback() {
            
            @Override
            public float reportRayFixture(Fixture fixture, Vector2 point, Vector2 normal, float fraction) {
                if ( fraction < SomeClass.this.closestFraction ) {
                    SomeClass.this.closestFraction = fraction;
                    SomeClass.this.collisionPoint.set(point);
                }
                
                return 1;
            }
        };
            
        world.rayCast(callback, fromPoint, toPoint);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I actually found the answer. If you return fraction instead of 1, it clips the distance if you invoke world.rayCast incursively. I think something wrong with your code. I f

Comment: So iv'e got the lowest number (the closest fraction), But how can i do something with the fixture now? How can i "print the closest fixture's class"?    


`if(fixture.getFilterData().categoryBits ==    FilterCollisionManager.ENEMY_BIT) {
                    ((ObjectManager) fixture.getUserData()).doSomeThing();`